# Best approach for querying multiple tables

Tags: sql-server, optimization, view

In SQL Server, I have a table, let's call it **Source**. The structure is

```
ID | SourceValue 
-----------------
1  |  'value1' 
2  |  'value1' 
3  |  'value2'
```

and so on.

*ID* is a primary key and *SourceValue* is not unique.

I also have several other tables which have *SourceValue*s in their records. As it's not unique, there is no Foreign Key constraint. This column also isn't UNIQUE in other tables. Furthermore, these columns can hold values both of `SourceValue` format and other formats. Because of this, I need to include a `DISTINCT`ed `SourceValue` data in the query.

I need to return `COUNT` of every occurence of *SourceValue* in all tables other than **Source**.

Our approach was to create a view which holds `DISTINCT` *SourceValue*s from the **Source** table, and then do the following:

```
SELECT q.SourceValue, SUM(q.Count) as Count
FROM (
  SELECT dvw.SourceValue, COUNT(dvw.SourceValue) AS Count
  FROM distinctValuesView AS dvw
  JOIN DependantTable1 dt1
  ON dvw.SourceValue = dt1.SourceValueColumn
  GROUP BY dvw.SourceValue

  UNION

  SELECT dvw.SourceValue, COUNT(dvw.SourceValue) AS Count
  FROM distinctValuesView AS dvw
  JOIN DependantTable2 dt2
  ON dvw.SourceValue = dt2.SomeOtherColumn
  GROUP BY dvw.SourceValue
) AS q
GROUP BY q.SourceValue
```

`distinctValuesView` is defined as

```
SELECT DISTINCT SourceValue FROM Source
```

The problem is there are more than 20 **DependantTable**s (transaction tables) and all these tables have tens of thousands of rows, with the **Source** table having more than 20.000 rows.

Naturally, this query is unacceptably slow (2 seconds execution time). Is there any other approach, or a way to speed it up?

Comment: The short answer is that you should write SARGable queries supported by the correct indexes. Without a lot more information like query plans, table and view definitions, and what indexes you have now, you're not likely to solicit anything more specific. It's up to you if you'd like to collect and share that much data with us.

Comment: @sp_BlitzErik Thank you for the comment. I'll see what more I'm allowed to share.

Comment: Change your UNION to a UNION ALL

Comment: Why does - for example - DependantTable1 dt1 contain SourceValue instead of Id from Source?

Comment: @Lennart I didn't design the database, I really wouldn't know.

Comment: Voting to close this question until we see table definitions and a plan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems a nice case to use an **Indexed View**.

With the indexed view, you will have a index on `SourceValue` and the `COUNT` (now `COUNT_BIG(*)`), will be materialized. Your query will run very fast.

Try to check the following script using indexed views. It should simulate the problem.

```
drop view if exists dbo.countDependantTable1
drop view if exists dbo.distinctValuesView
drop table if exists dbo.DependantTable1 
drop table if exists dbo.tbSource
go

create table dbo.tbSource
( ID int primary key
, SourceValue varchar(50)
)
go

insert into dbo.tbSource
select 1, 'value1' union all
select 2, 'value1' union all
select 3, 'value2'
go


create view dbo.distinctValuesView
with schemabinding
as
select SourceValue, COUNT_BIG(*) as Ct FROM dbo.tbSource group by SourceValue 
go
create unique clustered index IX_distinctValuesView on dbo.distinctValuesView (SourceValue)
go


create table dbo.DependantTable1 
( ID int primary key
, SourceValueColumn varchar(50)
)
go

insert into dbo.DependantTable1
select 1, 'value1' union all
select 2, 'value1' union all
select 3, 'value1' union all
select 4, 'value1' union all
select 5, 'value2'
go


create view dbo.countDependantTable1
with schemabinding
as
  SELECT dt1.SourceValueColumn, COUNT_BIG(*) AS Count
  FROM dbo.DependantTable1 dt1
  GROUP BY dt1.SourceValueColumn
go

create unique clustered index IX_countDependantTable1 on dbo.countDependantTable1 (SourceValueColumn)
go


SELECT q.SourceValue, SUM(q.Count) as Count
FROM (
  SELECT dvw.SourceValue, dt1.Count
  FROM distinctValuesView AS dvw
  JOIN countDependantTable1 dt1
  ON dvw.SourceValue = dt1.SourceValueColumn

  --UNION ALL

  --...

) AS q
GROUP BY q.SourceValue
```

Please also check:

**Create Indexed Views** - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/views/create-indexed-views?view=sql-server-2017

**SQL Server Indexed Views: The Basics** - https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/learn-sql-server/sql-server-indexed-views-the-basics/

Comment: This should really be a comment. It doesn't provide an answer to the question, just a speculative opinion. If there's a `LEFT JOIN` involved, it may not even be feasible to implement.

Comment: @Evandro Muchinski Thank you very much for the answer. I'll test it and accept if it helps.

Comment: Well, he is using an (INNER) JOIN in the example. The subqueries (between unions) can be splitted into Indexed views, one for each table he joins.

Comment: @EvandroMuchinski Your solution seems to be the way to go. The only problem is that I can't use another view, `DISTINCT` or derived tables in Indexed views. That is a problem because of the `distinctValuesView`. Would you kindly provide some advice for that?

Comment: Hi, i will edit the answer with a sample script to avoid this problems.

Comment: @EvandroMuchinski Although your answer didn't solve my problem because of other restrictions that surfaced during development, it did work for the scope of this question. So, I'm marking it as accepted. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why you join your dependent tables with the distinctValuesView. Is it to rule out sourceValues that does not exist in Source? In that case you may try to use `EXISTS` instead:

```
SELECT q.SourceValue, SUM(q.Count) as Count
FROM (
    SELECT dt1.SourceValue, COUNT(*) AS Count
    FROM DependantTable1 dt1
    WHERE EXISTS (
        SELECT 1 FROM Source s
        WHERE s.SourceValue = dt1.SourceValueColumn
    )
    GROUP BY dt1.SourceValue

    UNION ALL

    ...
) q
GROUP BY q.SourceValue
```

Note that I changed UNION to UNION ALL. I assume that if you have 4 occurrences of 'value1' in DependantTable1 and 4 occurrences in DependantTable2 the sum should be 8. If you use UNION the result will be 4

If most of your SourceValue exists in Source, you may try to apply the union first:

```
SELECT q.SourceValue, COUNT(*)
FROM (
    SELECT dt1.SourceValue
    FROM DependantTable1 dt1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT dt2.SourceValue
    FROM DependantTable1 dt2
) q
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM Source s
    WHERE s.SourceValue = q.SourceValueColumn
) 
GROUP BY q.SourceValue
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I explained why the view is needed. I apologize for leaving it out of the question, I forgot about that fact. `UNION ALL` is a skilled observation, you are completely right about that.